# Setting pipenv environment variable in venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv, python-venv

I am trying to set up a Python virtual environment with `pipenv`.
In VS Code, started in a fresh directory of Windows 10 OS, after doing:

1. `python -m venv work_env` in the Terminal
2. Noting the path of the *`Script`* folder within `work_env`
3. Doing `Ctrl-Shift-P` and `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings`
4. In `settings.json`, adding:

- environment path of Step 2 to *"python.pythonPath":*
- folder names to prevent pylance yellow squigglies to *"python.analysis.extraPaths":*

5. Doing a `pipenv install` in the Terminal
6. Updating package names in Pipfile
7. Doing `pipenv update` in the Terminal

... There comes a `Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, ... You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.`

In what folder / file / configuration do I set this `PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. According to the information you provided, I reproduced the problem you described:

   [image]
2. The reason is as this 'Courtesy Notice', "`pipenv install`" is to create a virtual environment for the current project, and we have created a virtual environment "`work_env`", so it prompts us to ignore this environment or
   Suppress this warning.
3. We can directly enter the command "`set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1`" in the console to suppress this warning:

   [image]

   After:

   [image]

The `pipenv` version I use is `2020.11.4`.

Update:

[image]

Comment: On # 3. Does directly entering the `set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1` command *once* in the Terminal permanently disables the `Courtesy Notice`? ... even after VS Code restart(s)?

Comment: @reservoirinvest -Don't worry, it will redisplay this prompt after using "set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=1". And you could refer to the update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Entering the command `set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1` didn't work for me.

So I added `PIPENV_VERBOSITY` variable and set the value to **-1** in the environment variable window

Setting Environment Variables:

1. Right-click on **My Computer** or **This PC** and select **Properties**.
2. Go to the **Advanced system settings** or Go to the Advanced tab in the System Properties window
3. Click the **Environment Variables** button. The Environment Variables dialog opens.
4. Click the **New** button under either User variables or System variables, depending on whether you want to set the variable for the current user or all users. To set environment variables for all users, you need to have administrator privileges.
5. In the Variable name field, enter the name of the environment variable you want to set. For a list of the environment variables that Nuke understands, see Nuke Environment Variables.
6. In the Variable value field, enter the value for the variable. The value can be a directory path, for example.
7. Click OK.

[image: Environment Variables Window]